# Use of Initialization Vector in a Hash Function

Tags: hash, algorithm-design, initialization-vector

Why is an Initialization Vector used in a hash function?

Some hash functions do not seem to need an IV, why do other hash functions need one?

Comment: Because hash functions are recursively defined to consume data and update state?

Comment: But we can find sometimes the specification of a hash function without an IV

Comment: @Guest16 Can you give an example? All the popular hashes I can think of have an IV (MD5, SHA1,2,3, Skein, Blake, Tiger, etc.) Technically it's possible to avoid IVs, but that doesn't seem common.

Comment: I have found it in a scientific research paper : in sometimes an IV is used to compute a hash value however in other times it is not used

please find a  screenshot of two different examples found in the paper

Comment: I  could not attach the secreenshot